# bear the seal/stamp of the county of New York

Tags: word-usage

I am wondering what it means to "bear the seal/stamp of the county of New York."

*i.e.*, This public document bears the seal of the county of New York.

Does this mean that the document physically has the seal on it or that it has been approved by the county of New York?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> This public document bears the seal of the county of New York.

This statement only explicitly states that the document visibly shows the seal of the county of New York.  It does *not* explicitly state that the county of New York approves, but it is implicit in the message.

Is it possible that the county of New York *accidentally* placed a seal on the document?  Possible, but not likely.  The point of putting such a message on the document is to bring it to the attention of the reader, so that meaning is strongly implied.

Answer (score 0):

To bear a seal means: to have a seal imprinted, printed or otherwise put on something, like a certificate or other formal document.

It is a word used to describe what a document or media is has on it. It comes from the idea of carrying something.

**Anything with a seal like that is usually an official document**. Of course, official documents can be falsified. So, I can say, this certificate bears the seal of New York county and it can have been falsified, though it is not easy to falsify seals.

There are many different kinds of seals: printed (like with a rubber stamp), imprinted, engraved, carved, etc. It's an entire world of stuff.